# Wordpress wp-cron.php execution doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, amazon-ses

I have a multisite WordPress.
I user WP Offload SES Lite to send emails.
One day emails stopped working.

In wp-ses I saw that many Emails are stuck in queue.
Sending test email worked with no problems.

After looking into the issue I found out that wp-cron.php doesn't work.
I tried to debug it and run wp-cron manually and there were no errors related to cron or to ses.
It looks like it doesn't run.

Tried to disable cron and activate alternate cron, like this:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true); /** Use alternate WP_CRON method with
redirects. */ define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true);
```

run it from cli and from url, trough browser and with Wget.

Nothing.
It started to happen around a week after an update.

I set up debugging with:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
```

That's the errors I see when running wp-cron:

```
[30-Jan-2021 22:13:12 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in /var/app/current/wp-includes/ms-settings.php on line 57
[30-Jan-2021 22:13:12 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in /var/app/current/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7-redirection-pro/classes/class-updates.php on line 71
[30-Jan-2021 22:13:13 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, bool given in /var/app/current/wp-content/themes/my-theme/admin/fields.php on line 2634
[30-Jan-2021 22:13:13 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, bool given in /var/app/current/wp-content/themes/my-theme/admin/product-search-fields.php on line 130
[30-Jan-2021 22:13:13 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  wpcf7_remove_shortcode is <strong>deprecated</strong> since Contact Form 7 version 4.6! Use wpcf7_remove_form_tag instead. in /var/app/current/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/functions.php on line 351
[30-Jan-2021 22:13:13 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  wpcf7_remove_shortcode is <strong>deprecated</strong> since Contact Form 7 version 4.6! Use wpcf7_remove_form_tag instead. in /var/app/current/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/functions.php on line 351
[30-Jan-2021 22:13:13 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: post_id in /var/app/current/wp-content/themes/my-theme/admin/product-search-fields.php on line 22
```

I have installed wp cli, and preformed :

```
wp  cron event run --due-now
```

That is the result:

```
PHP Notice:  Constant WP_DEBUG already defined in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1197) : eval()'d code on line 97
Warning: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, bool given in /var/app/current/wp-content/themes/my-theme/admin/fields.php on line 2634
Warning: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, bool given in /var/app/current/wp-content/themes/my-theme/admin/product-search-fields.php on line 130
Deprecated: wpcf7_remove_shortcode is <strong>deprecated</strong> since Contact Form 7 version 4.6! Use wpcf7_remove_form_tag instead. in /var/app/current/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/functions.php on line 351
Deprecated: wpcf7_remove_shortcode is <strong>deprecated</strong> since Contact Form 7 version 4.6! Use wpcf7_remove_form_tag instead. in /var/app/current/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/functions.php on line 351
Notice: Undefined variable: post_id in /var/app/current/wp-content/themes/my-theme/admin/product-search-fields.php on line 22
Executed the cron event 'deliciousbrains_wp_offload_ses_queue_connection' in 0.038s.
Executed the cron event 'wp_privacy_delete_old_export_files' in 0.031s.
Executed the cron event 'w3_cdn_cron_queue_process' in 0.034s.
Success: Executed a total of 3 cron events.
```

It looks like cron is runnign, but when I look into Offload SES Lite DIAGNOSTIC

```
INFO I see this: 
WP Cron: Disabled
Alternate WP Cron: Enabled
Last Run: 12:36:03 2021-01-07 UTC
Next Scheduled: 21:24:43 2021-01-30 UTC
Queued: 29
Failures: 878
```

It looks like ses cron get executed by emails are not getting send nor do they fail, they just remain stuck in queue.

I ran :

```
wp cron test
```

And got:

```
PHP Notice:  Constant WP_DEBUG already defined in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1197) : eval()'d code on line 97
Warning: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, bool given in /var/app/current/wp-content/themes/my-theme/admin/fields.php on line 2634
Warning: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, bool given in /var/app/current/wp-content/themes/my-theme/admin/product-search-fields.php on line 130
Deprecated: wpcf7_remove_shortcode is <strong>deprecated</strong> since Contact Form 7 version 4.6! Use wpcf7_remove_form_tag instead. in /var/app/current/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/functions.php on line 351
Deprecated: wpcf7_remove_shortcode is <strong>deprecated</strong> since Contact Form 7 version 4.6! Use wpcf7_remove_form_tag instead. in /var/app/current/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/functions.php on line 351
Notice: Undefined variable: post_id in /var/app/current/wp-content/themes/my-theme/admin/product-search-fields.php on line 22
Warning: WP-Cron spawn succeeded but returned HTTP status code: 403 Forbidden
```

Any ideas what can be wrong?
Also I only need cron for the emails. Is there a way to run wp-ses with cli?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to address any notice one by one, and try to build the solution.

Example:

Notice: Undefined variable: post_id in /var/app/current/wp-content/themes/my-theme/admin/product-search-fields.php on line 22
Warning: WP-Cron spawn succeeded but returned HTTP status code: 403 Forbidden

What is happening at line 22 on file themes/my-theme/admin/product-search-fields.php ?

Comment: I looked into it already. Nothing relevant to wp-ses, and notice or warning doesn't break execution.

Comment: @matisa it's not really like this, it doesn't stop execution but undefined variable, even if a notice, can ruin execution so actually break it in a subtle way: example, logic will not work as supposed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in one of my projects when `wp-cron.php` stopped working. I solved that via an alternate cronjob on the Linux server.

`*/5 * * * * cd /var/www/website_domain; php -q wp-cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: In my case there was a problem with the plugin, and no error. Changed the plugin and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem downgrading php version 8.2 to 7.4. Maybe plugin support to php +8 missing?